# golang SSL certification

Tags: ssl, go

So, here I am trying to have a socket listen on an SSL connection. However, it isn't able to make the handshake. Upon running

```
 sudo openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect localhost:8080
```

It is unable to verify the first cert.

I have very little experience with these SSL. Can anyone help?

```
  cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("positivessl.crt", "key.pem")
  Error.CheckError(err)                                                         

  rootCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt")   
  checkError(err)                                                         
  trustCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt")        
  checkError(err)                                                         
  validationCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt")
  checkError(err)                                                         

  certs := x509.NewCertPool()                                                   
  certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(validationCert)                                      
  certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(trustCert)                                           
  certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(rootCert)                                            

  sslConfig := tls.Config{RootCAs: certs,Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}} 
  sslConfig.Rand = rand.Reader                                                                                                       

  listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", service, &sslConfig)
```

Comment: You should use `s_server`, not `s_client`, as a server. If you are using `s_client` as a client, then there's no reason for `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with go itself, but from the documentation at http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/ they look similar to other SSL stacks:

- The `rootCert` should not be included in the chain. The root cert is the actual trust anchor used for verification at the certificate chain at the client and thus the client must already know it and trust it.
- `RootCA` are the trusted certificates which are used to verify the certificate. These are not send to the peer but used instead as the trust anchors when verifying the received certificates. Thus this setting is relevant for the client side to verify the servers certificate and maybe for the server side when the client send certificates too.
- Instead all the certificates you want to send to the peer have to be included in `Certificates`. That is, not only the leaf certificates `cert`, but also the chain certificates `validationCert` and `trustCert`. You have to include them in the correct order so that they build a chain which the client then can finish with the trusted root certificate.