# Android, Golang, and SSL

Tags: android, ssl, go

Here's the snippet of my code for just constructing an SSL socket on my android app. I have a go server which it is trying to connect to. I have signed certs, not self signed, but I still receive the error,

`trust anchor for certification path not found. android`

```
        SSLSocketFactory f = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

        try {
            SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket(ip, port);
            socket.startHandshake();
```

So, I cannot figure out if it is due to my server not being right or the android application. I have read on the main android website about this error, but it didn't really help me.

Here is the go code, maybe would shed some light somewhere

```
  cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("mycert_com.crt", "key.pem")
  checkError(err)                                                         

  rootCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt")   
  checkError(err)                                                         
  trustCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt")        
  checkError(err)                                                         
  validationCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt")
  checkError(err)                                                         

  certs := x509.NewCertPool()                                                   
  certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(rootCert)                                            
  clientCerts := x509.NewCertPool()                                             
  clientCerts.AppendCertsFromPEM(trustCert)                                     
  clientCerts.AppendCertsFromPEM(validationCert)                                

  sslConfig := tls.Config{RootCAs: certs, ClientCAs: clientCerts, Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}                                                 

  listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", service, &sslConfig)
```

Been stuck on this for a few weeks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the bad server as you would see when you try with `openssl s_client`.
See [golang SSL certification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578615/golang-ssl-certification) for the answer to a similar question from you on how to fix the server. And like I said there: according to the documentation you must put the intermediate certificates into `Certificates` and not into `RootCAs` or `ClientCAs`.